# How to mark up a tiled layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to mark up the page without javascript?
[image]

Both HTML elements (div1, div2) must to have fixed size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to work with the CSS attributes
[`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position), 
[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/top), 
[`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/bottom), 
[`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/left), 
[`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/right) and 
[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/height).
E.g.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; height:42px; background:green">div1</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; top:42px; background:red">div2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GPHEx/1/

- `position:absolute` lets you determine the layout in pixels and percent (roughly speaking).
- `left:0; right:0` make it full-width.
- `top:0` aligns a div to the upper edge.
- `bottom:0` aligns a div to the lower edge.
- `height:42px` and `top:42px` define the tiled layout.

[Vertical example](http://jsfiddle.net/KggQr/):

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; width:42px; background:green">d i v 1</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:42px; background:red">d i v 2</div>
</div>
```

[Example with four tiles](http://jsfiddle.net/xPsuC/1/):

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; height:80px; left:0; width:42px; background:green">d i v 1</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; height:80px; right:0; left:42px; background:red">d i v 2</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:80px; bottom:0; left:0; width:42px; background:red">d i v 3</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:80px; bottom:0; right:0; left:42px; background:green">d i v 4</div>
</div>
```

Notice how `top`+`height` resp. `left`+`width` work together.
You could have more tiles as well by adding the previous height to the next top.

With [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow) you can define what should happen if there is too much content. `overflow:auto` adds a scrollbar to the div if needed. `overflow:hidden` would crop it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GPHEx/2/. Content is out of the boundaries. I use Google Chrome.

Comment: See my update. overflow:auto/scroll is the way to go: http://jsfiddle.net/GPHEx/5/

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tried a layout like the one you have mentioned, you can try the technique mentioned here (negative margins.)

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins