# Getting desired layout in html with use of <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a div then inside the division have some different places where I can place stuff. For example.

```
<div blah>

<table blah>
content...
</table>

<table blah>
content...
</table>

<table blah>
content....
</table>


</div>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iprE.jpg]

I am not really a web developer so I know this question might seem simple but any help is greatly appreciated. Oh and I am using Macromedia Dreamweaver 8.

Thanks.

Comment: I answered almost the same question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10923596 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using three different divs and then using CSS to place the divs. Check out this w3 schools article on CSS positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware css positioning existed.

Comment: Ok for simplicity I want my css file separate from my html file.
So i just created a new position.css file 
Then i just created a simple file that contains.
table.pos{
left:100px
top:50px
}

how do import this css file to my html file?

Comment: so in your html, in between the `<head></head>` tags, place: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="position.css" />`. This will link your "position.css" file to the html file and look down at the other answers on this page for help with the CSS positioning.

Comment: Ok I've got everything linked up my css created except it doesn't seem to be working. 
Or at least not working the way I want it to.
<pre>/* CSS Document */
div.pos1{
 position:relative;
 left:225px;
 top:0px;
}
div.pos2{
 postion:relative;
 top:0px;
 left:100px;
}
div.pos3{
 position:relative;
 top:0px;
 left:100px;
 
}</code>

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the place for tutorials and "hello world"s, but here's something to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/rBNUy/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{  /* this makes the containing box 200x200  */
   width: 200px;
   height:200px;    
    background: #eee;
}
.sidebar{ /* this makes the sidebar 100x200 and makes it stick to as far left as it can */
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
}
.top, .bottom{ /* this makes the boxes 96x96 and makes them stick to as far left as they can , eventually till they hit the sidebar */
   width: 96px;
   height:96px;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    border:solid 2px green;
}
```

​comments are obviously over-simplified, but in essence, "floating" stacks elements onto one another very much the same as you would stack letters in a word.

When a floated element runs out of space to be stacked in the same line, it just hops to the next line, and finds the closest "wall" to stack to.

Answer (score 0):

In general, try not to use tables for non-tabular data - in other words, don't try to build a webpage using tables. Here is a good article which might get you thinking: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/

On a side note, a lot of people try to use w3schools for learning HTML and CSS. w3schools is an excellent reference for more experienced programmers, but I feel like it fails to teach novice programmers the big picture. You actually learn a lot from trial and error, and from looking at other people's work (source code). http://www.csszengarden.com/ has a great collection of webpages which will certainly help you pick up some new HTML and CSS techniques.

I implemented a rough solution for you of how (horrendous) your markup would have to look if you were to use tables.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/vMXQe/

HTML:

```
<table id="container">
    <tr>
        <td id="sidebar"></td>
        <td id="main">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
table { background: #000; }
td { background: #fff; }

#container { 
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
#sidebar { width: 35%; }
#main { width: 65%; }
#main table { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#main table tr { height: 50%; }
```